# Flask loop returning KeyError

Tags: python, json, python-requests, discord

I have a Flask application running 3 loops whenever the person opens/refreshes a specific page

First Loop:

```py
for i in range(0, 5):

    conversionToUsername = requests.get(
                f"https://discord.com/api/v9/users/{useridlist[i]}",
                headers={
                    "Authorization":
                    "Bot BOTTOKEN"
    }).json()["username"]

    conversionToDiscriminator = requests.get(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/users/{useridlist[i]}",
    headers={
                    "Authorization":
                    "Bot BOTTOKEN"
    }).json()["discriminator"]

    userIDtoName.append(f"{conversionToUsername}#{conversionToDiscriminator}")
```

Second Loop:

```py
for j in range(0, 5):
   coinslist.append(coins[str(useridlist[j])])
```

Third Loop:

```py
for l in range(0, 5):
    leaderboardlist.append(f"{userIDtoName[l]} => {coinslist[l]}")
```

Some important stuff:

I assigned `userIDtoName`, `coinslist` and `leaderboardlist` at module level, and I clear them before the loops are ran.

I send a request to the flask page that these loops are in every 10 seconds, and these requests change the values of `coins[str(jsondict[j])]`.

`coins` is a dictionary having keys of Discord user IDs, and values of integers (coins).

`useridist` is a list containing Discord user IDs.

Please tell me if this information is insufficient

So far, I've tried printing every statement, changing the `for i in range(0, 5)` to `for i in range(len(useridlist))` and `for i in useridlist`, merging them all into 1 and 2 for loops and running each statement in a Python IDLE Environment.

The error is that the line `conversionToUsername` (and sometimes `conversionToDiscriminator`) always return a KeyError, after a specific amount of tries. When I changed the request sending to once every 5 seconds, it showed the error after 3 requests. When I changed it to 10 seconds, it showed an error after 5 requests. But the error always appears whenever I refresh the page.

Does anyone have any clue on how to fix this, or what I did wrong?

Comment: i found the problem, not the solution. Its Discord rate limitations....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution. Instead of looking up every user's username via the discord API and facing ratelimits, instead I saved the user's ID with their username, so I don't have to send requests to discord everytime :D